# Best way to do data rebalancing in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

As of now, there's no native support for auto-rebalancing for Clickhouse. Say we need to add new nodes to the Clickhouse cluster and need to do a rebalance to make sure all the data still distributes evenly across all the nodes. Is there any existing tools/libraries available for this?

Comment: You can use clickhouse-copier and re-insert everything.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, since OP ask for external tools, but official answer from Clickhouse is:

> Rebalancing Data ClickHouse does not support automatic shard
> rebalancing. However, there are ways to rebalance shards in order of
> preference:
>
> Adjust the shard for the distributed table, allowing writes to be
> biased to the new shard. This potentially will cause load imbalances
> and hot spots on the cluster but can be viable in most scenarios where
> write throughput is not extremely high. It does not require the user
> to change their write target i.e. It can remain as the distributed
> table. This does not assist with rebalancing existing data.
>
> As an alternative to (1), modify the existing cluster and write
> exclusively to the new shard until the cluster is balanced - manually
> weighting writes. This has the same limitations as (1).
>
> If you need to rebalance existing data and you have partitioned your
> data, consider detaching partitions and manually relocating them to
> another node before reattaching to the new shard. This is more manual
> than subsequent techniques but may be faster and less
> resource-intensive. This is a manual operation and thus needs to
> consider the rebalancing of the data.
>
> Create a new cluster with the new topology and copy the data using
> ClickHouse Copier. Alternatively, create a new database within the
> existing cluster and migrate the data using ClickHouse Copier. This
> can be potentially computationally expensive and may impact your
> production environment. Building a new cluster on separate hardware,
> and applying this technique, is an option to mitigate this at the
> expense of cost.
>
> Export the data from the source cluster to the new cluster via an
> INSERT FROM SELECT. This will not be performant on very large datasets
> and will potentially incur significant IO on the source cluster and
> use considerable network resources. This represents a last resort.
>
> There is an internal effort to reconsider how rebalancing could be
> implemented. There is some relevant discussion here.

[Source](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/guides/sre/scaling-clusters)

So basically, we are limited to **copier**